# Why do jQuery.appendTo()/html()/... create global JavaScript variable automatically?

Tags: jquery

Sorry if this question is duplicate.

Recently I found jQuery would add global JavaScript variable after calling functions passing with DOM id, such as [`$('<div id="foo" />').appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) / [`$.html('<p id="bar" />)`](https://api.jquery.com/html/). The variable is pointed to the DOM object with the same id, shown as [these lines](http://jsbin.com/serasabeva/edit?html,js,console,output):

```
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <!-- include jquery.js -->
    <script>
         typeof(foo);                                          // "undefined"
         typeof(bar);                                          // "undefined"

         $('<div id="foo"></div').appendTo('#container');
         $('#foo').html('<div id="bar"></div>');

         typeof(foo);                                          // "object"
         typeof(bar);                                          // "object"

         foo instanceof HTMLDivElement;                        // true
         bar instanceof HTMLDivElement;                        // true

         foo === $('#foo')[0];                                 // true
    </script>
</body>
```

Is this feature introduced in the API documentation? What happens exactly?

Regards!

Comment: jQuery isn't doing this, the browser is. In some browsers, the element can be selected by `window.[elementId]` - which is happening here, example: https://jsfiddle.net/k7x4adu1/

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @RoryMcCrossan, it is not related to jQuery.

```
<script>
    var x = document.createElement("div");
    x.setAttribute('id', 'bar');
    document.body.appendChild(x);
    window.bar instanceof HTMLDivElement;  // true
</script>
```

See more details to this question [Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables)